# prove a function is not one-to-one

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let us look at the field $\mathbb{F}_{p}=\{0,1,2,...,p-1\}$ for a prime number p.

And let $f:\mathbb{F}_{p}\rightarrow \mathbb{F}_{p}$ be the function given by $f(n)=n^2 \space (mod \space p)$.

How do I show f is not one to one?

Comment: $f(1)=f(-1)$ is not one to one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT** Consider $f(n)$ and $f(p-n)$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}_p$. (Note that your assertion is true only for $p>2$.)

Comment: of course, thanks =]